# How to share a cache between multiple processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm using [a LRU cache](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498245/) to speed up some rather heavy duty processing. It works well and speeds things up considerably.  However...

When I multiprocess, each process creates it's own separate cache and there are 8 copies of the same thing.  That doesn't appear to be a problem, until the box runs out of memory and bad things happen as a result...

Ideally I only need a cachesize of around 300 items for the application, and 1*300 will fit in the 7GB i have to work with, but the 8*300 just doesn't fit.

How do I get all the processes to share the same cache?

Comment: The Python `multiprocessing` module has a section on [sharing state between processes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).

Comment: is an out-of-process cache an option for you?  Could you use pickle on your cached state and store it in, say, redis?

Comment: @sam Indeed, it appears the `Manager` can share a `dict`, which i suspect is the lfu cache is internally.  I guess I'm hoping someone has hacked that up before to suit this problem so I don't have to ;-)

Comment: @TokenMacGuy Like your thinking, but it's high-intensity (thousands per msec) so the mention of pickling has me immediately prejudging it too slow.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with different processes started by gunicorn + bottle?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto Interesting question, certainly worth searching for/opening up a new question for that. I assume you mean for sharing objects between requests.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe you can use a `Manager` to share a dict between processes. That should in theory let you use the same cache for all functions.

However, I think a saner logic would be to have *one* process that responds to queries by looking them up in the cache, and if they are not present then delegating the work to a subprocess, and caching the result before returning it. You could easily do that with

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as e:
    @functools.lru_cache
    def work(*args, **kwargs):
        return e.submit(slow_work, *args, **kwargs)
```

Note that `work` will return `Future` objects, which the consumer will have to wait on. The `lru_cache` will cache the future objects so they will be returned automatically; I believe you can access their data more than once but can't test it right now.

If you're not using Python 3, you'll have to install backported versions of `concurrent.futures` and `functools.lru_cache`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the shared cache to each process. The parent process can instantiate a single cache and refer it to each process as an argument...

```
@utils.lru_cache(maxsize=300)
def get_stuff(key):
    """This is the routine that does the stuff which can be cached.
    """
    return Stuff(key)

def process(stuff_obj):
    """This is the routine which multiple processes call to do work with that Stuff
    """
    # get_stuff(key) <-- Wrong; I was calling the cache from here
    stuff_obj.execute()

def iterate_stuff(keys):
    """This generates work for the processses.
    """
    for key in keys:
        yield get_stuff(key)  # <-- I can call the cache from the parent

def main():
    ...
    keys = get_list_of_keys()
    for result in pool.imap(process, iterate_stuff(keys)):
         evaluate(result)
    ...
```

This example is simple because I can look up the cache before calling the process.  Some scenarios might prefer to pass a pointer to the cache rather than the value.  eg:

```
        yield (key, get_stuff)
```

Katriel's put me on the right track and I would implement that answer, but, silly me, my mistake was even simpler to solve than what he suggested.

Comment: This will improve performance only if `get_stuff(key)` returns small objects, passing a large object to a child process will take a long time.